# How to force the twentyfourteen narrow screen layout to apply to wide screens?

Tags: responsive, theme-twenty-fourteen

In [gt.owenks.uk](http://gt.owenks.uk) uses the twentyfourteen theme.  The narrow screen layout uses the full width of the screen for posts and condenses the page menu to an icon:
[image]

But the wide screen layout uses only the middle third of the screen for posts.
[image]

How do I force the narrow screen layout to apply to all screens?

I tried using full page width template but that didn't work.

Comment: These are media queries in `style.css` and you will need to make many changes to do that. Although I think by removing all media queries at the bottom of `style.css` will make your website work like you want. But keep backup of your `style.css` file before you proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite an intensive operation if you look at it. I have done this once before. Before you start, you will need to understand what is happening.

The layout of full width pages are controlled by the `full-width` body class currently defined in [line 419 in functions.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/functions.php#L419). If the following conditions are met, the `full-width` body class is applied

- If `sidebar-2` don't have any widgets
- If one of the following pages are used:

  - page-templates/full-width.php
  - page-templates/contributors.php
- If the page is an attachment page

So bases on what you want to do, you would need to get rid of that conditions and apply the `full-width` body  class regardless

In a child theme, you will need to remove the full width body class and apply a new body class that will act as a new full width body class. Lets call this new class `new-full-width`. You can to the following now in your functions.php

```
function wpse168567_removes_full_width_body_class($classes) {
      foreach($classes as $key => $value) {
      if ($value == 'full-width') unset($classes[$key]);
      }
return $classes;
}

add_filter('body_class', 'wpse168567_removes_full_width_body_class', 20, 2);

//Add new body class 'new-full-width'
function wpse168567_add_new_body_class( $classes ) {
    $classes[] = 'new-full-width';

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse168567_add_new_body_class' );
```

You should now have the `new-full-width` body class set to all pages

You will now need to copy **all** instances of `full-width` from the main stylesheet in twentyfourteen to the stylesheet in your child theme. Once this is done, change all instances of `full-width` to `new-full-width`

You will now see that all pages are displayed at full width.

One last modification, remove `sidebar-2` from all templates and deregister it. This is important because if you drop any widget by mistake in that sidebar, it will mess up your layout, so to unregister that sidebar, do the following

```
function wpse168567_remove_right_sidebar(){
   unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpse168567_remove_right_sidebar', 11 );
```

You will have to copy all templates that calls this sidebar to your child theme and remove that call.

I can't remember right now if this is all you need to do. I do think that it might be necessary to adjust you content width as well